# MVC3 Ajax Ajax.ActionLink in Views Shared _Layout.cshtml

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an mvc3 web app I used a shared view under
Views
    Shared_Layout.cshtml

_Layout.cshtml contains markups which acts like a master page for our app

```
@using .............
@using ......

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="overflow: hidden">
    <head>
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/metro-light/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        @RenderSection("CSS", false)
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        ...... (some other scripts here)
        ......

    </head>
    <body style="height: 100%">
        <!-- page -->
        <div class="page">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="title">
                    <img alt="" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/Logo.png")"/>@ViewBag.ApplicationName
                </div>
                <div id="logindisplay">
                    Welcome <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>
                </div>
                <ul id="menu">              
                    <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Dashboard", "Index","Dashboard", new {@class = "Map View".Equals(ViewBag.Title) ? "selected" : null},new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "main", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET" })</li>
                    <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Map View", "Index", "Map", new { @class = "Map View".Equals(ViewBag.Title) ? "selected" : null },new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "main", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET" })</li>
                    <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Settings", "Index", "Settings", new { @class = "Settings".Equals(ViewBag.Title) ? "selected" : null }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "main", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET" })</li>
                    <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("About", "Index", "AppInfo", new { @class = "About".Equals(ViewBag.Title) ? "selected" : null }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "main", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET" })</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="main">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- footer -->
        <div id="footer">

        </div>
        <form id="__ajaxAntiForgeryForm" action="#" method="post">@Html.AntiForgeryToken()</form>
    </body> 

</html>
```

Basically, from the above code I am replacing my "main" div with whatever the controller return

```
new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "main", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET" }
```

Here are my controllers (nothing special)

*DashboardController*

```
[UiException]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

*MapController*

```
[UiExceptionAttribute]
public ActionResult Index()
{
return View();
}
```

When I load the page and click on the links "Dashboard" or "Map View", the whole page flickers and refresh.  Supposed to be @Ajax.ActionLink does not refresh the whole page but instead just the "main" div.  Is there a way to have an ajax like behavior refreshing only the content section?  Can anybody help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

it is because you are returning the whole view from controller code which includes the whole masterpage(i.e. ur layout).

You need to render only partial view of your dashboard or map.
like:

DashboardController

```
[UiException]
public ActionResult Index()
{
return  PartialView("yourviewname",model)
}


protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        ViewData.Model = model;

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi kj nap.. thanks, tho when I use PartialView it forces me to create a view in the _Shared.  I'm thinking of using an HTMLHelper to get view from the Views folder instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your unobtrusive Javascript include is missing so the action links are actually no "real" ajax links because no event handler have been attached to it (the unobtrusive-ajax script basically looks for all links with attribute data-ajax=true and attaches methods to it to do the ajax stuff).

So include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` file as well and it should work as expected.

Comment: Hi Marc, i've edited the above post see above.  Actually it does contain         <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>.  Does it have something to do with the version of jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

as above i found this useful too.. without putting the View on the _Shared folder.

```
/// <summary>
/// Dynamically Render a View using the passed-in context
/// </summary>
/// <param name="controllerContext"></param>
/// <param name="viewName"></param>
/// <param name="model"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string RenderView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, object model)
{
    controllerContext.Controller.ViewData.Model = model;
    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, viewName);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(controllerContext, viewResult.View, controllerContext.Controller.ViewData, controllerContext.Controller.TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
        viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(controllerContext, viewResult.View);
        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```